# Disable Extjs Form Validation Callout

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a grid, with contains form items.  Example below.  Link [here](http://www.turolight.com/test.php).  The form elements trigger a validator (ex: allowBlank: false), and pop up a callout.  The callout continuously flip flops, and annoys the users.  How to disable this callout.

```
{
    header: 'Item',                 
    width: 85, 
    sortable: true, 
    align : 'center',
    dataIndex: 'Item',
    editor: new Ext.form.TextField({
        id: "ItemName",
        blankText: "Item is required",
        allowBlank: false,                  
        selectOnFocus: true           
    })
},
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `errorSummary:false` to the RowEditor config.

Answer (score -1):

In the RowEditor.js file, set the following config:

errorSummary: false,

Comment: Actually, do NOT edit the RowEditor.js source directly.  Just pass the config when creating an instance in the app code, as I mentioned.